# C# ASP.NET with Bootstrap

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to generate anchors using @Html.ActionLink in a Bootstrap style Nav bar. I'm having trouble making the tabs switch active, what's the best way to accomplish this?

I've tried to append data-toggle="pill" to the a tags after the are generated but that doesn't seem to work.

Code:

```
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" id="myTab">
                <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Movies", "Index", "Movies")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Bootstrap Test", "Bootstrap", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code, though this might not be the exact problem you are facing, following blog post might help you to switch a tab dynamically.

https://madushaonline.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/active-links-on-bootstrap-navbar-with-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: I tried using this and the tabs switch / content loading works, but for some reason the anchor text is not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`overloaded ActionLink method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504988%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) which is accepting html parameters and pass the `@class=active` and you need to replace `data-` to `data_`(underscore) in MVC.

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li>
    @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new {@class = "active",  
                     @data_toggle="pill" })
  </li>
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Movies", "Index", "Movies")</li>
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Bootstrap Test", "Bootstrap", "Home")</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: What if I need to add an attribute to the anchor tag like data-toggle="pill" ?

Comment: @zeion, @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new Dictionary<string,Object> { {"class","active"}, {"data-toggle","pill"} })

Comment: @zeion, You need to use `@data_toggle`. Check my answer. In MVC for `data-` we need to replace `-` with `_`(underscore)